# How do I get the first 140 characters of text while making sure protecting last word?

Tags: jquery

How do I get the first 140 characters of a text, while making sure I am not breaking apart the last word?

So if the text is

```
Hello world my name is Amy Anderson.
```

And I want to get the first 13 characters:
It would be

```
hello world my ...
```

and not

```
hello world m
```

How do I do that using jquery?

Comment: Easy, get the first 13 characters, look at the last word, if it's incomplete, try 14, then 15, etc until you get a complete word. Or, split the text by word, then add words to the output until you have more than 13 characters.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use regex:

```js
var testString = "Hello world my name is Amy Anderson.";

// Replace 13 with whatever number you please
var regex_first13 = /^.{13}.*?(?=\s)/;

// If the regex returns nothing, 
// then string < 13 characters or ends on a word, 
// so use the whole string
var selection = regex_first13.exec(testString) || testString;

document.body.innerHTML = selection;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use jQuery for this - try this solution:

```js
var test = 'Hello world my name is Amy Anderson.';
var atest = test.split(' ');
var result = '';
var i = 0;
var maxlength = 13;
do {
  result = result + ' ' + atest[i];
  i += 1;
} while (atest.length >= i && result.length < maxlength);

document.body.innerHTML = result + ' ...';
```